# How to efficently set all values above a line in an binary image to 1?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, multidimensional-array

I currently have a binary image, stored as a 2D array of [col][row].
The image is split in 2 by a line and I want to set all array values above the line to 1.

Currently, I loop through the columns of the array, looping through the rows of the column (bottom to top) to find the first row where the value of the array [col][row] is 1. I then break from looping through the rows and set all values above the row that I broke from to 1 for that column.

Unfortunately for a 1920x1080 image, this takes about 3 seconds. How could this be achieved more efficiently?

```
for x in range(len(image)):
    col = image[x]
    minY= -1

    for y in range(len(col)):
        if image[x][-y] != 0:
            minY = y
            break

    if minY != -1:
        under = [0] * minY 
        over = [1] * (len(col) - minY)
        newCol = over + under
        image[x] = newCol
```

Before and After pictures below...

[image]
[image]

Comment: check `cv2.floodFill`

Comment: It seems that your line is doubled i.e. two close lines parallel to each other. Is that always the case? Any other cases?

Comment: @Baraa Yes this is always the case although the 'bottom' line is the line to fill from

Comment: Are they always close to each other, can I assume that the distance between them is not larger than a threshold 15 pixels for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a couple of methods requiring a 2D input.
May need to be adjusted to ensure they are working on the correct side and on the correct dimension, but the core idea holds.

- using `np.where()` and looping over one dim with slicing:

```
import numpy as np


def side_fill_np(arr, value, flag):
    rows, cols = arr.shape
    idx = np.where(arr == flag)
    for i in range(cols):
        arr[idx[0][i]:, idx[1][i]] = value
    return arr
```

- using full explicit looping (similar to yours, but somehow cleaner), but accelerated with `numba`

```
import numba as nb


@nb.jit
def side_fill_nb(arr, value, flag):
    rows, cols = arr.shape
    for j in range(cols):
        found = False
        for i in range(rows):
            if found:
                arr[i, j] = value
            elif arr[i, j] == flag:
                found = True
```

---

To test that we are getting the correct result, we generate some input using:

```
def gen_data(shape):
    rows, cols = shape
    arr = np.zeros(shape, dtype=bool)
    indexes = (np.random.randint(0, rows - 1, cols), np.arange(cols))
    arr[indexes] = True
    return arr
```

and the test reads:

```
np.random.seed(0)  # for reproducible results
arr = gen_data((10, 20))
print(arr.astype(int))
# [[0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
#  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0]
#  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
#  [0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
#  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
#  [1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
#  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]
#  [0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0]
#  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0]
#  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]

side_fill_np(arr, True, True)
print(arr.astype(int))
# [[0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
#  [0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0]
#  [0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0]
#  [0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0]
#  [0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0]
#  [1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1]
#  [1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1]
#  [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1]
#  [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
#  [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]]
```

---

Now for the timings for approx. your input size:

```
arr = gen_data((2000, 2000))
%timeit side_fill(arr, True, True)
# 1 loop, best of 3: 2.48 s per loop
%timeit side_fill_np(arr, True, True)
# 10 loops, best of 3: 52.6 ms per loop
%timeit side_fill_nb(arr, True, True)
# 100 loops, best of 3: 6.14 ms per loop
```

As you can see, with the NumPy approach (which is as much vectorized as I could think of) you get approx. 2 orders of magnitude speed-up, with the Numba accelerated code you get approx. 3 orders of magnitude speed-up.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cv2.floodFill` to fill all connected pixels within a range of values. You have to specify a `seed_point` from which the filling starts until blocked by a pixel with a value outside the specified range.

To solve the issue of the duplicate lines we need first to connect them. To do so, we can apply the closing morphological operation.

Code (~10 ms for the question image including the closing operation):

```
max_distance_between_lines = 15
closing_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT (max_distance_between_lines, max_distance_between_lines))
img = cv2.morphologyEx(img, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, closing_kernel)
point_in_top_half = (5, 5)
#floodFill works inplace, `img` is now filled
cv2.floodFill(img, None, point_in_top_half, 255)
```

[image]